# WordPress TinyMCE 4.2.8 is messed up in Firefox 43.0.1

Tags: wordpress, firefox, tinymce-4

I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm only experiencing this problem in Firefox 43.0.1

The editor is all messed up. I ran a Firefox updated, restarted my browser and now I'm having this issue. Here's an image of what I'm seeing now.

[image]

Also, not seeing the static WordPress menubar at the top when viewing my website now. Here's what I see instead:

[image]

Any idea what's going on since I updated FF?

This is what I see in the network console:
[image]

I just figured it out... Apparently, Google had flagged my js/css as malware. I disputed it and now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: It's not a FF update problem.  It's something wrong with the styles (and other assets) loading in your dashboard.  Turn on your Browser Console, go to the "Network" tab, and see what's happening - I suspect you're getting errors on all your js / css files (I use many WP sites, and none of them are "broken" due to the FF update).

Comment: @cale_b I just added an image of what I see in the network console. Why would this just happen since the update though? I've not had any problems until now.

Comment: Have you tried emptying your cache ?

Comment: I have @SamuelBellerose. I was privacy mode, so nothing should be cached. Also, I have the inspector open and I have nothing caching while it's open.